# Unlink system and ringer volumes

Tags: volume-control, volume

Does anyone know of a way to unlink the system and ringer volumes on Android oreo or pie? My goal is to have a loud ringtone while keeping the system sounds minimal or off altogether. If someone has a different solution for the desired goal that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Is the phone rooted? GravityBox xposed module can do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Are you sure there's a way of unlinking the ringer and system? I can only find reference to unlinking ringer and notification. I'm also reluctant to install GravityBox just for one setting.

Comment: Definitely sure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKON.jpg